# Perl/CGI script fails on large uploads

Tags: perl, upload, cgi, large-files

I have this Perl/CGI to upload files and get the uploaded file size while uploaded.

The script works fine for files under 500MB but the buffer (OUTFILE) stops writing the file after around 500MB.
Here's the partial code:

```
$u_size = $ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'};
if ($u_size > $max_size) {send_error ("Upload too big.  Maximum size is $max_size bytes and your file is $u_size bytes.");}

print_progress(0);
# Set up uploading function
$query = CGI->new(\&hook);

#define functions
sub hook  {
    if ($error) {return;}
    if (time >= $next_print) {
        $next_print = time + $delay;
        my ($filename, $buffer, $bytes_read, $data) = @_;
        if ($check_mime) {
            $filename =~ m/\.([^\.]+)$/;
            $ext = lc($1);
            print $ext;
            $check_mime = 0;
        }
        $percent = $bytes_read / $u_size;
        $filename =~ m/\\([^\\]+)$/;
        $filename = $1;
        print_progress($percent, $u_size, $bytes_read, $filename);
    }
}

sub print_progress {
    open(PROG, '>'.$uploaded_file_progress);
    print PROG '{"percent" : ' . ($_[0] * 100) . ', "total" : ' . $_[1] . ', "uploaded" : ' . $_[2] . ', "filename" : "' . $_[3] . '"}';
    close PROG;
}

#############

$uphandle = $query->upload($query->param());
binmode $uphandle;

if (!$error) {
    open OUTFILE, ">" . $uploaded_file;
    binmode OUTFILE;
    while($bytesread = read $uphandle, $buffer, 1024) {
      print OUTFILE $buffer;
    }
    #while (<$uphandle>) {print OUTFILE $_;}
    close OUTFILE;
}
```

If the script is not a problem, what other stuff that I have to check?
Thanks.

Edit: I have this in the log: Timeout waiting for output from CGI script.
How do I get rid of this? I couldn't find a definitive answer on Google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would imagine you need to poke your apache `TimeOut` configuration variable in the apache conf.

Seeing as you are using perl, this has been broached a couple of time on perlmonks.org and this link has popped up in response.

http://www.stonehenge.com/merlyn/LinuxMag/col39.html

Comment: Thanks for the direction to the `TimeOut` config. That's the only thing that was different on the two servers. I can't believe it was that simple.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to set the $CGI::POSTMAX to something greater than 500MB to see if that corrects the issue.

If I'm not mistaken, 500MB is the default for POSTMAX. I always set mine at 2GB (but then I use it to upload a lot of video!)

Answer (score 0):

There is an Apache httpd.conf 'MaxRequestLen' setting which is worth investigating (if you are using Apache).